# How do I run Python code that returns a CSV to replace the data in a Google Sheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a Python script that returns a CSV.  I want to view this data in a Google Sheet. Right now, I have to run my Python code, overwrite my old CSV file with my new data, then go into Google Sheets and import the new CSV and overwrite the Google Sheets data.  I want this to happen automatically. How do I do that?

I tried to run a macro, didn't work since I need to call code from my terminal right now. This is probably a pretty easy thing to do, but I can't figure it out. There are two things that sound like they would work: writing to Google Sheets from my terminal and running code straight from Google Sheets. I need it to be the second. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at the Google Sheets Python API might help: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

You'll have to do some setup, but this way you can interact with Google Sheets through Python.